# updating value of array's index and text file and listbox from textbox

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, listbox

I want to update specific item in listbox which stream text from .txt file from textbox in c#. here is the interface.

[image]

here the code I use to stream data from .txt file

```
static string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"Path");
```

so how I would be able to update for example model of Honda and change the Index array and text file in the same time?

Comment: _"here the code I use to stream data from .txt file"_ that's not a stream, you are reading all lines into a `String[]` at once.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as `File.WriteAllLines(@"Path", listBox.Items.Cast<string>())`

Comment: you're right Tim. I'm ok with reading data from text file I stock when I want to update one specific index of array from textbox. for example if I change model textbox to something else it has to change the value of array's index and textfile.

Comment: then you have to know the index of this bike in the array. Then you can overwrite it, for example: `string[] bikeInfo=new[]{txtModel.Text,....,txtCost.Text}; allBikeArray[index]=String.Join("\t", bikeInfo);`

Comment: awesome, that works. thanks mate